# I am trying to detect if I am colliding with a specific object in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my scene, there are multiple objects with the same layer and tag. I have a variable that will be set to the gameobject for one of these objects. I would like to do something when I collide with the object that is set to the variable.
My current code is:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.otherCollider == targetFood)
    {
        Debug.Log("I am touching food");
    }
}
```

I've tried a few different methods of checking if it is touching the food, but none have worked. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you get the game object from the collision, you should be able to determine if the target food has been touched.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject == targetFood)
        {
            Debug.Log("I am touching food");
        }
    }
}
```

This is assuming that `targetFood` is a variable that is of type `GameObject`.